# With help of Gauss theorem calculate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We have a vector field:

$$F = (xy^2, x^2y, 0)$$

We want to calculate flow through the edge:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \\
z^2 \leq x^2+y^2\\$$

What I tried:

Cylindrical coordinates, we get:

$$r+ z^2 \leq 1\\
z^2 \leq r^2\\$$

$r(\phi, r,z) = (r\cos(\phi), r\sin(\phi), z)$

Now I somehow need to use the theorem:
$\int_{D}F(r(t))\cdot (r_u\times r_v)du dv$

But however here we have 3 parameters, should I just do cross product three times then, so like
$\int_{D}F(r(\phi, r, z))\cdot (r_z\times r_{\phi} \times r_r)dr dz d\phi$.(We usually always got only two parameters )

Comment: Are you trying to use divergence theorem? At least that's what the title says. If so, you have to find the divergence and do the volume integral.

Comment: If you are using surface integral, there are two surfaces.

Comment: @MathLover By using divergence theorem I get: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}_z r^2 dr d\phi dz$

Comment: @MathLover Would that be correct

Comment: @MathLover However, wolfram says that this integral does not converge, so I dont know what I did wrong..

Comment: No that integral is not correct. I will correct it but first, I am not sure why you say the flow through the edges. Should it not be through surfaces that the region is bound by.

Comment: @MathLover Yes I think correct terminology would be through surfaces (I am translating from my native language).  However the solution should be $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed region is given by,

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1, x^2 + y^2 \geq z^2$

In cylindrical coordinates, $r^2 + z^2 \leq 1, r \geq |z|$

At the intersection of both surfaces $~2 z^2 = 1 \implies z = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Divergence of the vector field is $x^2 + y^2$ or $r^2$ in cylindrical coordinates.

So the volume integral should be,

$ \displaystyle 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1 / \sqrt2} \int_{z}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} r^3 ~ dr ~ dz ~ d\theta$